# How to use html option inside rails tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am using ternary operator in view form.But it showing syntax error.And I included code,So,Please check and let me know what I did wrong.

```
<td><%= i.is_approval ? <span class="label label-success">Approved</span>: "Pending" %></td>
```

It doesn't take the html code .It shows syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix.

```
<td><%= i.is_approval ? '<span class="label label-success">Approved</span>' : 'Pending' %></td>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add a .html_safe to be sure that the html code will be evaluate ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please Try with

```
<td><%= i.is_approval ? "<span class='label label-success'>Approved</span>".html_safe : "Pending" %></td>
```